# Способ для задания шаблона строки JAVA

Tags: java

Есть строка. Например:380501234567 Мне нужно изменить её по шаблону:+38(050)123-45-67. Есть ли способ без посимвольного перебора. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Вот так сделайте, через RegEx

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String number = "380501234567";
    String placeholder = "+$1($2)$3-$4-$5";
    String result = number.replaceAll("(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", placeholder);
    System.out.println(result);
  }
```

либо так

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try {
      String phoneMask = "+##(###)###-##-##";
      String number = "380501234567";

      MaskFormatter maskFormatter = new MaskFormatter(phoneMask);
      maskFormatter.setValueContainsLiteralCharacters(false);
      String result = maskFormatter.valueToString(number);
      System.out.println(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
  }
```

не забываем подключить

```
import javax.swing.text.MaskFormatter;
```

во втором случае